# Meaning of "fact of nature" in a paragraph

Tags: expressions, translation

A friend of mine is translating a text about the Millennial Generation and asked me about the meaning of "fact of nature" in the excerpt "technology wasn't a **fact of nature** at these times". It is part of a paragraph where a person (who is not part of Millennial Generation) explains that he or she is not a "digital native".

This really got me. Is this supposed to mean "something that was natural", or something else? Is there another way to say it?

Comment: It just means something that we take for granted without thinking about it, that's all. It's "a fact of nature" that women's clothing styles in the USA change faster and more thoroughly than men's clothing. Even though it's simply a cultural tendency, not natural at all.

Comment: By the way, "technology" has been with us since the dawn of civilization, though we didn't always call it that.  Fire was a new technology at one time, as was the axe, the wheel, or pottery; anything that was conceived by people, which made a task  easier.